# Crystal Report is not loading without error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am generating simple Crystal Report in VS-2012 from SQL Server 2014, unfortunately it is not loading/showing content in the browser. Showing no error.

What I did is, added Project, Added crystal report and configured with SQL Server database, drag and drop items, preview in visual studio is show correctly as data is in SQL Server. I haven't added any extra Dataset or DataTables becuase I am gettinf my data directly from SQL server

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CrystalReports
{
    public partial class ShowReports : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseString"].ConnectionString);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!IsPostBack)
               {
                    CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = false;
                    //CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
               }
        }


        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument myReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath(@"CrystalReport1.rpt");
            myReportDocument.Load(reportPath);
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            string query = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomer";
 con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;

            adp.Fill(dt);
            myReportDocument.SetDataSource(dt);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReportDocument;
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is that a published website? if so please make sure you are publishing aspnet_client folder, where are the crystal runtimes files

Comment: @cojimarmiami No this is not published.

Comment: do you have subreports?